# How to make child element overlay the parent element?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-position

I am using only CSS and Flexbox to build a responsive page. I have a child element that should "overflow" outside the parent element as shown here:

[image]

```
<div class="container-hero">
  <div class="hero-content">
    <h1>Tech Challenge</h1>
      <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit </p>
   </div>
   <div class="hero-img">
     <img src="assets/image-1.jpg">
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container-hero {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  margin: 40px 0;
}

.hero-img {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.hero-img img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;

}


  .hero-content {
    background-color: #D64C31;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    align-self: flex-end;
    width: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    padding: 40px 60px;
  }
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```css
 .container-hero {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  /* overflow-x: hidden; */
  position: relative;
  margin: 40px 0;
}

.hero-img {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.hero-img img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;

}


  .hero-content {
    position:absolute;
    background-color: #D64C31;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 40px 60px;
    bottom: -20px;
    left:0;
  }
</div>
```

```html
<div class="container-hero">
  <div class="hero-content">
    <h1>Tech Challenge</h1>
      <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit </p>
   </div>
   <div class="hero-img">
     <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/800x300">
   </div>
</div>
```

The property you are looking for is CSS Position.

Reference: [CSS Position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

```css
.parent{
  width:250px;
  height: 20px;
  background: yellow;
  position:relative;
}
.child{
  width:80px;
  height: 100px;
  background: purple;
  position:absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I just posted my code above. I am using relative and absolute properties. One of the child elements is an image that I need to be 100% width and this is where I am getting confused about how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Like that?

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .container {
            background: #ccc;
            width: 50%;
            margin: 0 auto;
            position: relative;
            height: 700px;
        }
        .overflowing-element {
            background: red;
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
            position: absolute;
            right: -200px;
            top: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        test
        <div class="overflowing-element">
            bla
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Just works with fixed width of that overflowing element, or with JavaScript.

EDIT: You just edited your images and now I don't know really what you mean :D

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out, thank you for your help!

My parent element had an `overflow: hidden` I disabled it and adjusted the child element as follows:

```
bottom: -40px
```

If you have any feedback or this is considered a bad practice please let me know. I am just starting out here :)

Comment: If any of the other answers also worked or help you get here, you could consider accepting one of them so that your question gets marked as resolved on the site and you also get a few rep points :) Or when you get enough reputation, consider upvoting the useful answers, as well as thanking the user who helped, it lets other users know the answer might help them too

Answer (score 0):

Use the CSS positioning properties.

```css
.container-hero {
  position: relative; /* creates the container for absolutely positioned children */
}

.hero-content {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -20px;  /* use this offset to align vertically */
  left: 20px;     /* use this offset to align horizontally */
  background-color: #D64C31;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  width: 225px;
  padding: 40px 60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-hero">
  <div class="hero-content">
    <h1>Tech Challenge</h1>
    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit </p>
  </div>
  <div class="hero-img">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x250.png?text=hero image">
  </div>
</div>
```